# Hide or delete a non-existant folder from git terminal

Tags: git

We set up our magento site in git.

When we run this command `git status`, we can see the following files as an image:

[image]

but as mentioned in above image "Marketplace OLD 3" directory does not exist in server.

We tried this command to delete it: `git rm -r app/code/local/Webkul/Marketplace OLD 3` but we are getting error as:

```
fatal: pathspec 'OLD' did not match any files
```

So we added "Marketplace OLD 3" directory in server and tried to delete through git, but still it's not working.

How to hide or delete the above files from git terminal?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12565308/1746118 could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see *deleted xxxxxx*, It means you have deleted files but have not staged this modification. please use *git add --update* to stage it.

*git rm* will delete files and at the same time stage this deletion, so it will return error when you want to *git rm* not existing files.

Comment: i used this : `git add --update' now all files showing in Green color, now  how i can remove those files from terminal

Comment: Showing in green color means you can run *git commit* to commit your deletion now.

Comment: but i dont want to commit those files

Comment: @BabyinCoding Here commit means delete index of files from repository.

Comment: i iwll commit those fles

Comment: it will commit all modified files right ? becuase before i ran `git add --update` this command

Comment: @BabyinCoding You can use *git add --update your_file* to stage deleted file only.

Answer (score 2):

`git clean -fd` shall clean the files and directories not on the server from your local directory.

Comment: i found this error : `fatal: pathspec 'OLD' did not match any files`
 after running command

Comment: which directory are you running this command from? post running this command git either removes unused directories and files and return their pathname or returns nothing

Comment: i am running from root directory ,