# How to recover files to staging area after commit?

Tags: git, git-bash

Using GitBash, after I used the command git commit -m "some message" the files on staging area disappeared.  They cannot be added back even though I used the command git add filename.  How should I do to take those file back?

Thanks.

Comment: The thing is that _normally_, the files on your working tree are like the ones in the last revision.... so sure, if you add them, git won't do a thing because they are already like in the last revision... and also the index (a.k.a. staging area... because the index actually has the information about all files from last revision _plus_ what you add to create the next revision).... so, what you see is expected. What are your expectations?

Comment: I am relatively new to Git and don't know much.  What I would expect is, after a commit, it should be possible that I will modify those files again in the future.  I have to be able to put those file back onto the staging area.  How can I do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Sure.... in order for you to be able to put them in the staging area after you commit, you need to set them with a different content from what you have in the last commit. Then you will be able to add them into the staging area.

Comment: I think this link can partially solve my query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564855/git-rm-cached-and-fatal-pathspec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the files on staging area disappeared

No, the files did not disappear. Say

```
git ls-files --cached
```

The output is a list of the files in the staging area. As you will see, all your files are there.